# Perf. issue / Too much calls to string manipulation functions

Tags: php, string, templates, optimization

This question is about optimizing a part of a program that I use to add in many projects as a common tool.
This 'templates parser' is designed to use a kind of text pattern containing html code or anything else with several specific tags, and to replace these by developer given values  when rendered.

The few classes involved do a great job and work as expected, it allows when needed to isolate design elements and easily adapt / replace design blocks.

The patterns I use look like this (nothing exceptional I admit) :

```
<table class="{class}" id="{id}">
    <block_row>
        <tr>
            <block_cell>
                <td>{content}</td>
            </block_cell>
        </tr>
    </block_row>
</table>
```

*(Example code below are adapted extracts)*

The parsing does things like that :

```
// Variables are sorted by position in pattern string
// Position is read once and stored in cache to avoid
// multiple calls to str_pos or str_replace
foreach ($this->aVars as $oVar) {
    $sString = substr($sString, 0, $oVar->start) .
            $oVar->value . 
            substr($sString, $oVar->end);
}

// Once pattern loaded, blocks look like --¤(<block_name>)¤--
foreach ($this->aBlocks as $sName=>$oBlock) {
    $sBlockData = $oBlock->parse();
    $sString = str_replace('--¤(' . $sName . ')¤--', $sBlockData, $sString);
}
```

By using the class instance I use methods like 'addBlock' or 'setVar' to fill my pattern with data.

This system has several disadvantages, among them the multiple objects in memory (one for each instance of block) and the fact that there are many calls to string manipulation functions during the parsing process (preg_replace in the past, now just a bunch of substr and pals).

The program on which I'm working is making a large use of these templates and they are just about to show their limits.

My question is the following (No need for code, just ideas or a lead to follow) :

- Should I consider I've abused of this and should try to manage so that I don't need to make so many calls to these templates (for instance improving cache, using only simple view scripts...)
- Do you know a technical solution to feed a structure with data that would not be that mad resource consumer I wrote ? While I'm writing I'm thinking about XSLT, would it be suitable, if yes could it improve performances ?

Thanks in advance for your advices

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension to profile your code and find out exactly which parts of the code are taking the most time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did and through that and kCacheGrind I made several improvements, despite that still to many calls of php internal functions. I'll try few ideas I have left, finally I'll probably restrict the use of this class to elements that are not repeated too many times. I'll post there if I find out another solution :) thanks again.